# Media uploader not work properly

Tags: uploads, media

I am uploading media via the Wordpress media uploader. It says it uploads the file fine (and if I check inside my uploads folder, it is in fact there).

But the image is broken on the frontend, and if I go to the media uploader, it shows a broken image.

[image]
[image]

Now the strange thing, is if I click 'edit image' in the media uploader, it shows me the image...

[image]

the link to the image is also correct except when I use that link to view the image I am taken to a 404 page.

I would like to add that I de-activated all the plugins I am using and there is no change. As well, I've given the uploads folder permissions of 777. No change.

The uploader works fine on my remote server, but this happens when I use the site locally (using MAMP).

I just want to know what the problem is and if it is something that will occur when I set the site live on another server...What is going on?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you paste the File URL into the address bar? 404? What are the broken image URLs? How do those compare to the working images' URLs in "edit image"

Comment: Well, the one that works is an ajax call while the other one is just the link to the image (which should work)

Comment: Found the problem. I had a .htaccess file in the uploads folder that was preventing it from working.

Comment: @jasonaburton - please, add the solution as an Answer, so this Question doesn't hangs in the "Unanswered" category...

Answer (score 0):

The OP had a `.htaccess` file in the uploads directory