# Wordpress FTP/media directory permissions problem?

Tags: plugins, permissions, ftp

I keep having problems when I try to update or download plugins in Wordpress, I keep getting a "Directory not created".
Also, when I try to upload images, there is always "permission denied" problems.

Comment: Are you developing locally?

Answer (score 0):

May be this is the same problem : [Can't upload media, permissions are correct](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161123/cant-upload-media-permissions-are-correct).

At first, change permission (chmod) with filezilla or another ftp client to 755.